# subtracting one from another in matlab

Tags: matlab, time

My time comes back from a database query as following:

```
kdbstrbegtime =
    09:15:00

kdbstrendtime =
    15:00:00
```

or rather this is what it looks like in the command window.

I want to create a matrix with the number of rows equal to the number of seconds between the two timestamps. Are there time funcitons that make this easily possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) to convert both timestamps into serial numbers, and then subtract them to get the amount of seconds:

```
secs = fix((datenum(kdbstrendtime) - datenum(kdbstrbegtime)) * 86400)
```

Since the serial number is measured in days, the result should be multiplied by 86400 ( the number of seconds in one day). Then you can create a matrix with the number of rows equal to `secs`, *e.g*:

```
A = zeros(secs, 1)
```

I chose the number of columns to be 1, but this can be modified, of course.

Comment: thank you very much - just a beginner and was not aware of the datenum function so much appreciated

Comment: @user2126062 If this answer resolved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark (✓) next to the voting buttons.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert `kdbstrendtime`  and `kdbstrbegtime` to `char` by `datestr` command, then:

```
time = datenum(kdbstrendtime )-datenum(kdbstrbegtime )
t = datestr(time,'HH:MM:SS')
```